# How to set image name in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, tags, dockerfile

You can set image name when building a custom image, like this:

```
docker build -t dude/man:v2 . # Will be named dude/man:v2
```

Is there a way to define the name of the image in Dockerfile, so I don't have to mention it in the `docker build` command?

Comment: For anyone curious, using [FROM... AS name](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) does NOT work

Comment: Workaround using Docker and a Makefile; and, an alternative with `buildah` https://stackoverflow.com/a/75538276/124486 Hope you find this answer a bit more useful then telling you that can't or telling you the same command as in the question.

Answer (score 542, accepted):

## Workaround using `docker-compose`

Tagging of the image isn't supported inside the Dockerfile. This needs to be done in your build command. As a workaround, you can do the build with a docker-compose.yml that identifies the target image name and then run a `docker-compose build`. A sample docker-compose.yml would look like

```
version: '2'

services:
  man:
    build: .
    image: dude/man:v2
```

That said, there's a push against doing the build with compose since that doesn't work with swarm mode deploys. So you're back to running the command as you've given in your question:

```
docker build -t dude/man:v2 .
```

Personally, I tend to build with a small shell script in my folder (build.sh) which passes any args and includes the name of the image there to save typing. And for production, the build is handled by a ci/cd server that has the image name inside the pipeline script.

Comment: Upvoting this because this actually answers the question in the first sentence "Tagging of the image isn't supported inside the Dockerfile". Only once you know this are you interested in considering workarounds...

Answer (score 96):

## Workaround using `docker-compose`

**Updated**: "container_name" names the container that's ultimately spun up from the image. "image" names and tags the image created, from which the container is built. As others have mentioned, one cannot specify the image name from the Dockerfile, as the OP asked, so we use the docker-compose.yml file instead, and run it with "docker-compose up -d --build

Here is another version if you have to reference a specific docker file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    image: my_nginx:latest
```

Then you just run

```
docker-compose build
```

Comment: I like it that this answer shows the difference between the container_name and the image name:tag. If only there was a little more explanation of what's going on: "container_name" names the container that's ultimately spun up from the image. "image" names and tags the image created, from which the container is built. As others have mentioned, one cannot specify the image name from the Dockerfile, as the OP asked, so we use the docker-compose.yml file instead, and run it with "docker-compose up -d --build"

Comment: @SeanMcCarthy With your current score you could edit the answer and put the explanation into it.

Comment: good idea. i did it.

Answer (score 18):

My `Dockerfile` alone solution is adding a shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S docker build . --tag=dude/man:v2 --network=host --file

FROM ubuntu:22.04
# ...
```

Then `chmod +x Dockerfile` and `./Dockerfile` is to go.
I even add more `docker build` command line arguments like specifying a host network.

NOTE: `env` with `-S/--split-string` support is only available for newer coreutils versions.

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but comes with a small caveat: Because Docker sees the shebang line _as a comment_, you cannot use [parser directives](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#parser-directives) in such a file (such directives must be at the very start of the file, and not even comments may precede them).

Answer (score 8):

With a specific Dockerfile you could try:
`docker build --tag <Docker Image name> --file <specific Dockerfile> .`
for example
`docker build --tag second --file Dockerfile_Second .`

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround using Docker (and a Makefile)

Generally in Docker you can't say what you want the image to be tagged as in the `Dockerfile`. So what you do is

- Create a `Dockerfile`
- Create a `Makefile`

  ```
  .PHONY: all
  all: docker build -t image_name .
  ```
- Use `make` instead of invoking `docker build` directly

## Or, use `buildah`

But here is a better idea... Don't build images with Docker! Instead build them with [`buildah`](https://buildah.io/), the new build tool provided by the podman crew which uses shell (or any language), allows building in the cloud easily (without using a different project like `kaniko`), and allows rootless building of images! At the end of the build script just save the image inside with `buildah commit`. Here is what it looks like.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Create a new offline container from the `alpine:3` image, return the id.
ctr=$(buildah from "alpine:3")
# Create a new mount, return the path on the host.
mnt=$(buildah mount "$ctr")

# Copy files to the mount
cp -Rv files/* "$mnt/"

# Do some things or whatever
buildah config --author "Evan Carroll" --env "FOO=bar" -- "$ctr"

# Run a script inside the container
buildah run "$ctr" -- /bin/sh <<EOF
  echo "This is just a regular shell script"
  echo "Do all the things."
EOF

# Another one, same layer though
buildah run "$ctr" -- /bin/sh <<EOF
  echo "Another one!"
  echo "No excess layers created as with RUN."
EOF

# Commit this container as "myImageName"
buildah commit -- "$ctr" "myImageName"
```

Now you don't have to hack around with a `Makefile`. You have one shell script that does everything, and is far more powerful than a `Dockerfile`.

---

*Side note, `buildah` can also build from `Dockerfile`s (using `buildah bud`), but this short coming is with the `Dockerfile`. So that won't help.*

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and run the below mentioned command :

`docker build -t imagenameHere:tagHere .`