# How could you name your docker images based on directory name?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I'm looking to use docker more frequently, and I ended up with a template directory structure a bit like:

```
My-New-Project/
    |- Dockerfile
    |- build.sh
    |- start.sh
    |- src/...
```

Where `build.sh` &  `start.sh` are just the usual `docker build -t my-new-project .` and `docker run -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd):/workdir my-new-project`

However, I need to modify the image name in `build.sh` & `start.sh` for every new project - how could I use bash to set the image name based on the directory basename.

Also, if there are best practices against doing what I'm doing please let me know.

Comment: I find your approach a bit good, maybe I'll try it. But for now, I use this [approach](https://medium.com/@paulredmond/my-simple-approach-to-using-docker-and-php-b8f6ee76f43c).
Concerning your bash question: did you try to explore the **basename** command?

Answer (score 2):

Combining the answers from [How to set image name in Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986057/how-to-set-image-name-in-dockerfile) and [Get current directory name (without full path) in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-a-bash-script), all you need to do in your build.sh and start.sh is to:

`docker build -t "${PWD##*/}"` and `docker run -p 8888:888 -v $(pwd):/workdir "${PWD##*/}"`

Or, assuming you also need the name to be lowercase as in your example ([How to convert a string to lower case in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash)):

```
dirname=${PWD##*/}

docker build -t "${dirname,,}"
```

`${PWD##*/}` uses shell parameter expansion to remove the other directories from the path, and `,,` is another one that converts upper to lowercase.

Comment: Maybe note that `${dirname,,}` is Bash 4+ only. Poor macOS users are still on Bash 3.x out of the box. The other parameter expansion is compatible with any shell, Bash or POSIX `sh`.

Comment: Thank you, this looks great - except I am a poor macOS user - how do you cast to lowercase in bash 3.x?