# docker change image name?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm creating an image via docker compose, but for some reason the name is getting doubled?

Everything is working great, and there are not problems, but the image names looks like 'poc_tool_poc_tool"
How can I change the name? or add versioning?

docker ps:

```
c70753c4553e   poc_tool_poc_tool   "streamlit run --ser…"   17 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes   0.0.0.0:8889->8889/tcp   poc_tool_poc_tool_1
```

The project is built as follows:

```
- poc_tool
   - app1
   - app2
   - app3
   - docker-compose.yml
   - Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster AS build
COPY app3 /app
COPY app1/src /app/src
COPY app2 /app/app2
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8889
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit","run","--server.port","8889"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  poc_tool:
    build: .
    volumes:
      ...
    ports:
      - "8889:8889"
```

Answer (score 7):

Compose generates its own names for most things, and it usually does this by combining the [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) (by default, the name of the current directory) with the name in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  If you look at `docker ps` output, you'll probably see a container named `poc_tool_poc_tool_1`; if you look at `docker network ls`, you'll see `poc_tool_default`; and if you had named volumes, they'd also have this prefix.

In the `docker-compose.yml` file, it's valid to specify both [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) and [`image:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#image).  If you do, then `docker-compose build` uses the `image:` name instead of generating its own.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  poc_tool:
    build: .
    image: registry.example.com/name/poc_tool:${TAG:-latest}
```

(Style-wise, this means you don't generally need to include the project name as part of your Compose service names.  It also means it's important to *not* name `image:` as the base image of your Dockerfile, since Compose will happily overwrite it with your application code.)

Answer (score 3):

```
 docker rename CONTAINER NEW_NAME
```

also check this for naming it in docker-compose

[How to set image name in Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986057/how-to-set-image-name-in-dockerfile)

Answer (score 1):

for versioning your docker images, you can use `docker tag` as below.

```
docker tag registry.example.com/OlderName registry.example.com/NewName:Version
```