# Docker image name is <none> after build

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, virtual-machine

I want to create a Dockerfile that has node.js, here is my code:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app
```

After executing the command `docker build .` and checking my image with `docker image` it says `<none>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
docker build -t image_name .
```

**--tag , -t* --> Name and optionally a tag in the 'name:tag' format

Answer (score 3):

I understand what you are trying to do. However a little more detail would be nice.

To answer your question, you have at least two methods. The first method would be to tag the image like so: `docker build -t image_name .`

This is probably the most basic and simplest way. However, if your building this image over and over, then you may want to use a second method, a docker-compose file, like so:

```
version: '3'

services:
  service:
    build: .
    image: image_name
```

Inspiration for these examples taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986057/how-to-set-image-name-in-dockerfile)

If either of these work for you, please don't forget to accept this answer.

Comment: If the linked question answers this one, please flag this as a duplicate rather than adding an answer pointing at it.