# '<unknown> Dockerfile: Dockerfile' has been deployed successfully

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, intellij-idea

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM amazoncorretto:19-alpine3.16-jdk
WORKDIR /app
ARG JAR_FILE=target/spring_jwt-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} ./app.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

How to set name, tag for Docker image?

[image]

Comment: You can name your Docker images and container instances in the Run configuration.

Comment: The `docker build -t` option does this.  It looks like you included an image of some sort in your question; how is that PNG file related to your application or the Docker build sequence?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38986057/596285